# Value extracting from html form, using Groovy or Velocity

Tags: html, groovy, velocity

Could somebody tell me what would be the most appropriate way to extract value from HTML input form using either groovy or velocity. So that I can use it further in my groovy/velocity code.

```
<form>
   First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br> 
   Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: You will always get better responses if you start by showing what you tried.  If that answer to that question is "nothing", the question might not be a good match for StackOverflow.  [StackOverflow is not a forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Where does the html file comes from? You download it? Or it is in the same project?

Comment: If it helps code is like...
    {{velocity}}
    {{html}}
    <form name="createItemFrm" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" value="" size="10" name="spaceName" id="itemid" 
    </form>
    {{/html}}
    {{/velocity}}

in the middle of course there are some irrelevant velocity and html but none of that has anything to do with that.
What i need is to get value from input form so that i can use it further in my code. (in xwiki system)